# Python: Single Quotes Showing up in my Database

Tags: python, database, mysql, string, regex

I'm doing some python programming, inserting data into a MYSQL database for a project. I've been doing the coding, but noticed an odd artifact; Whenever I insert string data, my database includes the single quotes (') on either side of the string that I'm inserting.

Code looks like this, with 'data' being a large string I'm searching:

```
chars = r" -~"
shortest_run = 10    
regexp = '[%s]{%d,}' % (chars, shortest_run)

pattern = re.compile(regexp)

for current in pattern.finditer(data):
    temp_array = (current.start(), current.group(0))
    c_cursor.execute(base_insert,(temp_array[0], temp_array[1]))
```

Upon insertion, the database has values that look like this:

```
'Thisisthestring'
```

when it should just be:

```
Thisisthestring
```

The single quotes shouldn't be there, but they are.  I can't remove them with python statements (like string[1:-1]) because they don't actually exist within the variable.

Any thoughts?

ADD: 'base_insert' is a simple SQL INSERT statement that puts the values into a table. Looks a little like this:

```
Insert Into Strings_Output_tbl (Offset, Strings_out)
Values ("%s","%s")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I figured it out.

Having double quotes in the base_insert SQL is what is screwing it up.  The .execute adds the single quotes as part of it's process. So, having the double quotes there is messing everything up.  Better base_insert:

```
Insert Into Strings_Output_tbl (Offset, Strings_out)
Values (%s,%s)
```

Now, when called with .execute, no single quotes in my DB.

In retro, obvious.

Comment: You are using SQL parameters. One of the stated responsibility of a SQL parameter is to figure out the quoting needed to represent your value safely as part of a SQL statement. For strings, it'll add quoting. For integers, it won't add quoting. Etc. Your quotes embedded in the query where thus *extra*, redundant, making MySQL think there were double quotes present in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried supplying .execute with the string parameter?

```
c_cursor.execute(base_insert,(temp_array[0], temp_array[1]), s)
```

Additionally, you should have a look at the [guidelines](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters) for database queries: Try to avoid Python's built-in string functions, as they may open your code to injection.

Comment: Tried now, but s is undefined.  Throws an error. I think I'm using the correct methods to make the queries, no '%' operator being used.

Comment: Additionally, c_cursor is a 'MySQLdb' cursor, which only takes 2 parameters.

Comment: Heh.  Funny thing is, if I used c_cursor.execute(base_insert % (temp_array[0], temp_array[1]) ) it would actually work.